# Why isn't `value` being automatically narrowed to type `number` in this example?

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why "value" isn't narrowed to `number` in this TypeScript function. I'm thinking, if `T` is `Property.Height` then `Data[T]` should be of type `Data[Property.Height]` which is `number`

```js
enum Property {
    Height = 'height',
    Name = 'name',
    DateOfBirth = 'date_of_birth'
}

interface Data {
    [Property.Height]: number;
    [Property.Name]: string;
    [Property.DateOfBirth]: Date;
}

function example<T extends Property>(value: Data[T], property: T) {
    if (property === Property.Height) {
        // why isn't "value" narrowed to number here?
    }
}
```

Comment: These two arguments are seen independent by the compiler, a possible fix is demonstrated [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAxYBN). Does it work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript is not currently able to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to affect [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *type parameters* like `T` inside the body of `example`.  So while checking `property === Property.Height` will narrow the type of `property`, the `T` type parameter itself will stubbornly stay the same.

One reason `T` doesn't change is because it is not correct to say that checking `property === Property.Height` implies that `T` is `Property.Height`. The [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T extends Property` doesn't mean "`T` is exactly one of the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members of `Property`".  It can be any subtype of `Property`, including the full `Property` union itself.  Let's see what happens if we call example()` with union types:

```
// this does not cause a compiler error:
example(new Date(), Math.random() < 0.001 ? Property.DateOfBirth : Property.Height); 

// function example<Property.Height | Property.DateOfBirth>(
//    value: number | Date, property: Property.Height | Property.DateOfBirth
// ): void
```

That call is *allowed*, and you can see that `T` has been inferred to be the union `Property.Height | Property.DateOfBirth`, which means that `Data[T]` is inferred to be `number | Date`.  In that call there is a 99.9% chance that `property === Property.Height` while `value` is *definitely* `Date`.  Oops.

There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) asking for some other syntax instead of `T extends Property`.. maybe say something like `T oneof Property` meaning that `T` must be exactly one member of the `Property` union.  And then maybe the compiler could use `property === Property.Height` to conclude that `T` is `Property.Height` and you'd get the behavior you want.  But for now it's not part of the language.

---

Right now, if you want to use `if`/`else` or `switch`/`case` case analysis inside your function, generics won't really help you.  Instead, the supported way to do that is with [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  I could refactor that code to look like:

```
type ExampleArgs = { [K in Property]: [value: Data[K], property: K] }[Property]
/* type ExampleArgs = 
  [value: number, property: Property.Height] | 
  [value: string, property: Property.Name] | 
  [value: Date, property: Property.DateOfBirth] 
*/

function example(...[value, property]: ExampleArgs) {
  if (property === Property.Height) {
    value.toFixed(); // works
  }
}


example(new Date(), 
  Math.random() < 0.001 ? Property.DateOfBirth : Property.Height); // error!  
example(new Date(), Property.DateOfBirth); // okay
```

I don't want to digress too much to explain how that was computed, but you can see that now `example` isn't generic; instead it takes a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of a discriminated union type, where the second argument *discriminates* the argument list.  And you can't make bad calls with it anymore, as shown above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewA7DgFwJ5QN4CgpQASwAlgOYAWaUAvFAOQWmVr0A0+UAcgIYTC0GIPsHacAIjzTAA8gDMAQiXQVB9ACZTgAfQRztAI2VoK9XAF9cuEiGlw5PAMYDJaHjk4BteMlSYAdMTkVAC6AFxQ4BAGqADcXj4o6Bj+vPzhUADOaHA2ZPEE3ohJAa6yisYUGWXxlrhyYCCOaCQIIFDAAB58SAA2wAA8ACodndIg6pmwxX4YAHwAFABuPL1gwBGuPJ5DIWxQSDPJEUMAlB4EJHJQC4e+ybQ0dImzgcxU53gEBAD0P1AAdwoWBImRA9GoACIVmtgJDIjw4IgAcB1FA0AhIpAYnAoEw4MAAPzfKCcSx1Lo9foLEDAAFQMoLU77ACyUgo-jgPAmCAgTKgAygAAZ-EKhQBGKDEl7JfxleRKFRQCIygJBFineJ-KANJotNqjKmDVUpdVUKAAH2m91KWgVlUWuG13xh6wiURxloZWn2dxKGBVRzV72oVpNcrtFRUTv+pwiSwQJHUVmE-EySCcAgAYiROh5OJgUFAAKLdCB9YAAQTgZCmdGwUE8AGkoDZrf6Mp5XRtvW5m3sDkGA1AmyEoOYijaMCFOD8AFTojBF0tG6u1wScEld1ZurHRVC+oeBqdvYJoMdWzffbewiLZXIgMiHqfH-2pEQX0kkwrdzY+wcvu2rzylGJhjpwc4-FYBC6s0rTtJS5bUv4KE3usz4dhEK5IVWNaZJ8V5XDcfqzI8zxDqeGoXN+3b+BiOadKiTKxFA2oAggcAANaZFelgEHUBCIRWNJ0r2wBMqy7Kcty6i8vygoimKkrShRIGKiYypAbKZpoJqrH-KgiBwAAhAQnBCdStL0oyzJaba0j2ioenaggnE8FgpLQfpOqNHBBoWcaFE6V64ZqQ6Cyzv8Lo7j2HqoF6ZQYbMr6vMFYaqZG6kUJFUBxlACZJhYQA)